# JPA @Query select on oracle throws ORA-01722: invalid number on string

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have the following query that **works perfectly with ms-SQL but failing with oracle**

there is sample query, the original is way complicated but this one reproduces the error

```
@Query("SELECT new Map((s.name + ' - ' + s.name) as name , s.idStandard as idStandard) FROM Standard s ")
```

jpa model

```
public class Standard
{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int idStandard;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    @NonNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "UpdateUser")
    private String updateUser;


    @Column(name = "UpdateDT")
        private Date updateDt;
}
```

why oracle thinks this is  (s.name + ' - ' + s.name) is a number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the world deserves to know :) using concatenate operator || solves the problem!!
concatenate operator allows you to concatenate 2 or more strings together.

see the doc for more info
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat2.php

updating the query runs on ms SQL and oracle

```
@Query("SELECT new Map((s.name || ' - ' || s.name) as name , s.idStandard as idStandard) FROM Standard s ")
```

Comment: @Jonathan Johx well, from yesterday .. the original query is very big I had to break it down to find the issue

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein It's OK, someone will give you thanks for this answer. Thanks for letting us know it, if you have some question related to `Spring Boot`, `JPA` , etc let me know :) I like to know a lot of questions answered and not answered. Kind regards.